# how to "pop" a numpy int64 from a list made with list(df.jaar.unique())

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

First some simple example code, after that my problem (code)":

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
type(mylist)
type(mylist[0])

while mylist:
    mylist.pop(-1)
```

result:

```
list
int
4
3
2
1
```

In reality a have a long function that takes data from a df wit 44K rows.

In my real function I make a list called: jaar.

```
jaar = list(df.jaar.unique())
    print(type(jaar))
    print(type(jaar[0]))
```

(to print statements are just for testing)
result:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So.... based on the example code I wanted to use jaar.pop(0) in my function.
But.... this gives an Error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I wanted to change the type of the jaar list elements with

```
jaar.astype(int)
```

This gives:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

then I tried this (found it on Stack and checked numpy.org):

```
jaar = np.dtype(object)
```

Result of this is:

```
KeyError: 'There are no fields in dtype object.'
```

So my question:

I make a list with:

```
jaar = list(df.jaar.unique())
```

result: [2016, 2017, 2018]

How to convert the values in jaar to values that can be popped like in the simple example. Basically: how to convert the numpy int64 to python integers so the pop() method works.

thank you all for helping me out! greetings Jan

Comment: It's not integer that you can pop, it's list. You should be able to pop `jaar = list(df.jaar.unique())` already.

Comment: hey. outside my function it works as it should: jaar.pop(0) indeed deletes the value of 2016. I tried it again in my function and then the Error is: AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'pop.... must be something going on in my function. Thanks for answering, I am going to check out my function again.... greetings Jan

Comment: I don't see any function in your post. Are  you sure you are passing the list to the function?

Comment: Quang Hoang,  the list is in the function. I changed the while part and the pop() code is now in the beginning of the function. and now it works! I will write the changed while code as an answer to my question. Annoying is that I dont understand why it works this way and not the first way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists have pop method, but ndarrays doesn't.
So in your example you can convert your ndarray to integers first with astype:

```
jaar = df.jaar.unique().astype(int)
```

And then you can convert this ndarray to list with command (like you already do):

```
jaar = list(jaar)
```

And now the method `pop` have to work:

```
jaar.pop(0)
```

It works for me with this example data:

FULL CODE EXAMPLE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'jaar':[1,2,3,4]})

jaar = df.jaar.unique().astype(int)
jaar = list(jaar)
jaar.pop(0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the while part to:

```
while len(jaar) != 0: 
        year = jaar[0] 
        jaar.pop(0)
```

the jaar.pop() was originally in the end of the function. Now in the changed way it works! thanks for helping. greetings Jan